# ActivityResultLauncher in Google Authentication gives resultCode=RESULT_CANCELED using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose, google-oauth

While trying to opt for Google Sign In after selecting the google account from the dialog the result launcher callback always return status 0 (RESULT_CANCELLED)

Already enabled Google Sign method in firebase, and updated the local google-services.json in project as well.

Somehow, the activityResultLauncher is not getting the right status, also tried using singleTop navigation approach but still the issue persists

Found few solutions where you need to sign OAuth Consent Form tried that solution but still receiving the same error.

Already tried the approach in this article:[One Tap Sign in - Activity Result with Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70850989/one-tap-sign-in-activity-result-with-jetpack-compose)
Already using ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult() still the issue persists.

Here is my Activity Code

```
class LoginAndRegistrationActivity : ComponentActivity() {

  private val viewModel: GoogleSignInViewModel by viewModels()

  private val googleAuthSignInClient by lazy {
    GoogleAuthSignInClient(
      context = this,
      oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this)
    )
  }

  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
      PokidexAppTheme {
        val navHostController = rememberNavController()
        if (googleAuthSignInClient.getSignedInUser() != null) {
          startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
        }
        NavHost(navController = navHostController, startDestination = "register_home") {
          composable(route = "register_home") {
            val loginState = viewModel.loginState.collectAsState()
            val googleSignInLauncher =
              rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
                onResult = { result ->
                  result.data?.let {
                    if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                      lifecycleScope.launch {
                        val signInResult = googleAuthSignInClient.signInWithIntent(
                          it
                        )
                        viewModel.onSignInResult(signInResult)
                      }
                    } else {
                      val exception = result.data?.getSerializableExtra(
                        ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult.EXTRA_SEND_INTENT_EXCEPTION, Exception::class.java)
                      exception?.printStackTrace()
                    }
                  }
                })
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = loginState.value.isSignSuccessful) {
              if(loginState.value.isSignSuccessful) {
                Toast.makeText(
                  this@LoginAndRegistrationActivity, "Google Sign-In Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                startActivity(Intent(this@LoginAndRegistrationActivity, HomeActivity::class.java))
                viewModel.resetState()
              } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                  this@LoginAndRegistrationActivity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
              }
            }
            RegistrationHomePage(
              onNavigationClick = {
                 navHostController.navigateUp()
              },
              registerWithEmailClick = {
              navHostController.navigate("email_reg") {
                launchSingleTop = true
              }
            }, registerWithGoogleClick = {
              lifecycleScope.launch {
                val googleSignIn = googleAuthSignInClient.signIn()
                googleSignIn?.let {
                  try {
                    googleSignInLauncher.launch(
                      IntentSenderRequest.Builder(it).build()
                    )
                  } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                  }
                }
              }
            })
          }
          composable("email_reg") {
            EmailRegistrationPage(onNavigationClick = {
              navHostController.navigateUp()
            }, onContinueClick = {
              navHostController.navigate("pass_reg") {
                launchSingleTop = true
              }
            })
          }
          composable("pass_reg") {
            PasswordRegistrationPage(onNavigationClick = {
              navHostController.navigateUp()
            })
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the GoogleAuthSignInClient.kt class

```
class GoogleAuthSignInClient(
  private val context: Context,
  private val oneTapClient: SignInClient
) {

  private val firebaseAuth = Firebase.auth

  suspend fun signIn(): IntentSender? {
    val result =
      try {
        oneTapClient.beginSignIn(generateSignInRequest()).await()
      } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        if (e is CancellationException) throw e
        null
      }
    return result?.pendingIntent?.intentSender
  }

  suspend fun signInWithIntent(intent: Intent): GoogleSignInResult {
    val credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(intent)
    val googleIdToken = credential.googleIdToken
    val googleCredentials = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleIdToken, null)
    return try {
      firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(googleCredentials).await().user?.let {
        GoogleSignInResult(
          googleUserData = UserData(
            userId = it.uid,
            userName = it.displayName,
            profileImageUrl = it.photoUrl?.toString()
          )
        )
      } ?: run {
        GoogleSignInResult()
      }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      e.printStackTrace()
      e.printStackTrace()
      if (e is CancellationException) throw e
      GoogleSignInResult(
        errorMessage = e.message
      )
    }
  }

  fun getSignedInUser() = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.let {
    UserData(
      userName = it.displayName,
      userId = it.uid,
      profileImageUrl = it.photoUrl?.toString()
    )
  }

  suspend fun signOut() {
    try {
      oneTapClient.signOut().await()
      firebaseAuth.signOut()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      e.printStackTrace()
      if (e is CancellationException) throw e
    }
  }

  private fun generateSignInRequest() =
    BeginSignInRequest.builder().setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
      BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
        .setSupported(true)
        .setServerClientId(context.getString(R.string.firebase_client_id))
        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
        .build()
    ).setAutoSelectEnabled(true).build()
}
```

Stuck in this issue for while now and anyone help, Thank you.